# Hiding C sources when using lcov with a language transpiled to C

Tags: c, code-coverage, lcov, transpiler

I'm experimenting with a language (ooc) that transpiles into C and is then compiled using `gcc`. I want to check code coverage for a project written in this language and display it using `lcov` and `genhtml`. The C code has `#line` references throughout the file pointing to the corresponding file in the original source.

So far so good, I have it setup and working. *But* `lcov` seems to generate results for both the orignal source and the generated C code, which bloats the output.

How can I hide results for the C code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve this on my own.

After the initial `lcov` call, but before `genhtml`, call for example:

`lcov --remove <info-file> '/usr/include/*' -o <info-file>`

Where `<info-file>` is the `.info`-file generated by lcov in the initial step.